# Адаптация сайта под мобильные и планшеты

Tags: bootstrap

Здравствуйте. Помогите пожалуйста адаптировать сайт. Учусь сайтостроительству только несколько месяцев, и это мой второй пример, когда не получается адаптировать сайт под мобильные и планшеты... Использую bootstrap(пытаюсь использовать). [Сам сайт](http://magical-pen.ru) 
Пытался прописывать col-xs и 12 и 6.. и col-md добавлял.. Всё равно не адаптируется... Получается, что ширина блоков где "купить 3D ручку", они всё равно шире, чем шапка и остальная часть сайта.... Помогите пожалуйста!!
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Тоже долго мучался с одним сайтом. Потом сделал заметку сам для себя, чтобы не забывать. Может кому пригодится [http://royal-site.ru/verstka/kak-sdelat-adaptivnyj-dizajn-sajta-pod-vse-razresheniya-ekrana/](http://royal-site.ru/verstka/kak-sdelat-adaptivnyj-dizajn-sajta-pod-vse-razresheniya-ekrana/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте [меди-запросы](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries):

```
<!-- CSS media query on a link element -->
<link rel="stylesheet" media="(max-width: 800px)" href="example.css" />
```

или

```
<!-- CSS media query within a stylesheet -->
<style>
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .facet_sidebar {
    display: none;
  }

}
</style>
```

смысл в том, что css правило срабатывате только когда экран достигаете указанной ширины. Т.е. для мальнеких экранов вы пишите одни стили, а для больших другие. И разруливаете это всё с помощью, `@media (max-width: XXXpx)`

Comment: а мне нужно дополнительно к медиа запросам , еще указывать в html col-xs и прочие форматы?

Comment: нет не нужно. col-xs - это бутстраповский @mediaquery - http://getbootstrap.com/css/